# Prove Bernstein’s inequality for martingales

Tags: martingales, filtrations

I am new to machine learning theory and recently read Lamma A.8 in P363 of the book [Prediction, Learning, and Games](https://ii.uni.wroc.pl/%7Elukstafi/pmwiki/uploads/AGT/Prediction_Learning_and_Games.pdf):

**Bernstein’s inequality for martingales**: Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ be a bounded martingale difference sequence with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}=(\mathcal{F}_i)_{1\le i\le n}$ and $|X_i|\le K$. Let
$$
S_i=\sum_{j=1}^i X_j
$$
be the associated martingale. Denote the sum of the conditional variances by
$$
\Sigma_n^2 = \sum_{t=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_t^2|\mathcal{F}_{t-1}]
$$
Then for all constant $t,v \gt 0$,
$$
\mathbb{P}\Big[\max_{i=1,\cdots,n} S_i \gt t,\Sigma_n^2 \le v\Big] \le \exp\bigg(-\frac{t^2}{2(v+Kt/3)}\bigg)
$$

The book omits the proof but refers to [another paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2959268.pdf) on the tail probabilities for martingales. After checking, however, I still have little clue about constructing its full proof yet.

Many thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: Wainwright's "High-Dimensional Statistics" gives a Bernstein-type bound for martingales with a proof in section 2.2.2. Maybe this helps.